# for loop stop in the first iteration

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop

for loop in below java code stop in the first iteration, I don’t know why! 
can you help me?

controllerSwitches elements is { 1, 2}

allSwithces elements is {1,2,3,4}

```
for (int p = 0; p < controllerSwitches.length; p++) 
{  
    switches tempSwitch = controllerSwitches[p];
    for (int w = 0; w <= allSwithces.size(); w++)
    {
        System.out.println(tempSwitch.getSwitchId() +"\t" + allSwithces.get(w).getSwitchId());
        if (allSwithces.get(w).getSwitchId().equals(tempSwitch.getSwitchId())) 
        { 
            failedControllerswitches.add(allSwithces.get(w)); // it is break after getting the first p index  
        }
        continue;
    }
    continue;
}
```

it gets the first p index and compare it with all element of allSwitches list, then its break the loop. I mean it doesn’t go to the second p index.
the output is

1 1

1 2

1 3

1 4

it does not compare the second element of controllerSwitches with allSwithces elements

Comment: Aren't you getting some error because of `w <= allSwithces.size()` in your inner for loop? Some kind of IndexOutOfBounds maybe? No?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `continue` statements?

Comment: both of those `continue` statements are not inside of a conditional block, so they're definitely going to be hit on the first loop every time.  `continue` doesn't mean "do the next iteration of the loop", it means "stop this loop and continue at the next instruction after the loop"

Comment: Have you tried putting the continue inside the if ?

Comment: @Gus I think you have `break` and `continue` mixed up. `for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {System.out.println(i);continue;}` will output 0 through 9.

Comment: @DTing hah! you're right; I blame it on the late night.  In that case they're not wrong, just unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

1. Outer loop is terminating because inner loop is throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundException` at the end of the comparison.

Change

```
        for ( int w = 0; w <= allSwithces.size() ; w++)
```

to

```
        for ( int w = 0; w < allSwithces.size() ; w++)
```

and all combinations will be printed.

2. You are not breaking in the inner loop. Just comment says that it should break but code doesn't.
3. You `continue`s are redundant as code will automatically continue. Remove them.

Additionally, putting complete code would have helped as you definitely would have received an exception in the caller.

Comment: the problem now is, after ending the loop, it doesn’t complete the rest of the code in the function :|

Comment: What do you mean? What is the output and what is the code?

And again, you can accept the answer!